# Shopware6: disable cache with SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED=0 but cache is still enabled

Tags: caching, shopware6

I have set

```
SHOPWARE_HTTP_CACHE_ENABLED: 0
```

as environment variable.

The Backend verify it that it is enabled.
[image: cache-backend]

But when im now changing something at the shopware frontend (editing a site), the fronted don't get changed until i rebuild the cache with bin/console or the "Cache clear" button in the backend (screenshot).

Answer (score 2):

With "changing anything at the shopware frontend" you mean twig? Then you're looking for the TWIG-Cache: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/caches#twig-cache

Try setting it to false.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to aforementioned twig cache, please note that caches in Shopware are multi-layered. Aside from the http cache there's also the [object cache](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/hosting/performance/caches#object-cache) which, for example, caches results from the data abstraction layer. The simplest way to deactivate the object cache would be to change the `APP_ENV` environment variable to `dev`, as the object cache is not used in `dev` environment by default.

If you want to stay in the `prod` environment and use a memoized cache instead, you may create `config/packages/framework.yml` and add this:

```yaml
framework:
    cache:
        app: cache.adapter.array
```